# Colour transition JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I've noticed a site that seems to have a very nice colour transition effect on the background. When a link is pressed the background changes colour, however it doesn't seem instant. A transition seems to take place..

http://fuelbrandinc.com/#/about

I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to replicate this functionality?

Thanks,

Comment: Wow, that site is beautiful! You can look at that site's JS. No there is no copyright on such little things as transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using **[jQuery](http://jquery.com)** JavaScript library and the **[jQuery Color animations plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)**.

You can see this by inspecting the `compiled.js` file from source line 202 onwards via your favourite DOM inspection tool.

Answer (score 1):

When you described the effect, I was picturing something horrible, but it actually didn't look that bad at all.

You can use the `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to make code execute at specific intervals. Example:

```
var cnt = 0;
var handle = window.setInterval(function(){
  $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#'+'0123456789ABCDEF'[cnt++]+'00');
  if (cnt == 16) window.clearInterval(handle);
}, 100);
```